# Implementation of PostMessage for TWA android application

Tags: postmessage, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

Used this documentation. Works.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/post-message-twa

BUT! If we change `"relation" in assetlinks.json: ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"]`
to `"relation": ["delegate_permission/common.use_as_origin"]`, as indicated in the article - the address bar appears in the application.

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple ones in the json

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.use_as_origin"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "your package name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["your sha 256"]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "your package name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["your sha 256"]
    }
  }
]
```

However I have the issue that it's not reaching `onMessageChannelReady`.

If I call `requestPostMessageChannel` in `onCustomTabsServiceConnected` it returns `true`.
Inside the callback `onRelationshipValidationResult`, the result is `false`. Therefore it's not validated

Did you have that issue ?

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks!
Sorry, i meant this example. Code in article didn't works 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos/twa-post-message